# Is Isolated Barrier Necessary for Equipment with Hazardous Area Certification Ex e ib mb I IC T6 Gb?

Tags: electrical-engineering

The equipment holds the certification Ex e ib mb I IC T6 Gb, where "ib" signifies intrinsic safety. This certification confirms that the equipment is specifically engineered to restrict electrical energy, prevent the occurrence of sparks, and minimize excessive heat that could potentially ignite an explosive environment.

Given this "ib" certification, is it accurate to state that isolated barriers are not necessary since the equipment already meets the required safety standards?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this needs location information, local and national regulations etc